# Java read unsigned int, store, and write it back

Tags: java, types, unsigned-integer

I need to read an unsigned int from a quicktime file, and write it back to another quicktime file.

Currently I read the unsigned int into a Long but while writing it back I never managed to write the exact number back in 4 bytes as unsigned int. The long has the correct value that I need to write back.
(eg 3289763894 or 370500)
I am unable to even read the write a number smaller then Integer.MAX_VALUE (eg 2997).

I am using the following methods to write the value back

```
 public void writeUInt32(long uint32,DataOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    writeUInt16((int) (uint32 & 0xffff0000) >> 16,stream);
    writeUInt16((int) uint32 & 0x0000ffff,stream);
    }


public void writeUInt16(int uint16,DataOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        writeUInt8(uint16 >> 8, stream);
        writeUInt8(uint16, stream);
    }


    public void writeUInt8(int uint8,DataOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        stream.write(uint8 & 0xFF);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In java there's no such thing as unsigned int. And a long has 8 bytes.

Comment: Because of it long is the closest thing we get to an unsigned int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write your long casted to int. I checked:

```
PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream ();
PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream (pipeOut);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream (pipeOut);

long uInt = 0xff1ffffdL;

System.out.println ("" + uInt + " vs " + ((int) uInt));
os.writeInt ((int) uInt);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) System.out.println (pipeIn.read ());

uInt = 0x000ffffdL;
System.out.println ("" + uInt + " vs " + ((int) uInt));
os.writeInt ((int) uInt);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) System.out.println (pipeIn.read ());
```

Output is

```
4280287229 vs -14680067
255
31
255
253
1048573 vs 1048573
0
15
255
253
```

as expected

Comment: The int overflows for some values since the network/quicktime int has a larger capacity than what java int can accomodate

Comment: There's no way you can fit into 4 bytes a value lager then 2^32 - 1. And provided code will work correctly for any number less then 2^32.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to read, store and rewrite it, then you can just use int.
More general: as long as you do not interpret the bits you can just read, store and write them without caring about the *intended interpretation* of the bits.