# Reading uint16 to image java

Tags: java, image, binary, bufferedimage

I have a .bin file that has been created in a MATLAB code as uint16 and i need to read it in Java.

With the code below, I get a blurry image with a very bad grayscale and the length of the file seems to be the double of the amount of pixels. There seems to be some loss of information when reading the file this way. Is there a way to read .bin files other than inputstreams?

This is how I try to read the .bin file:

```
is = new FileInputStream(filename);
dis = new DataInputStream(is);

int[] buf = new int[length];
int[][] real = new int[x][y];

while (dis.available() > 0) {
    buf[i] = dis.readShort();
}
int counter = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < y; k++) {
        real[j][k] = buf[counter];
        counter++;
    }
}
return real;
```

And this is from the part from the main class where the first class is called:

```
BinaryFile2 binary = new BinaryFile2();
int[][] image = binary.read("data001.bin", 1024, 2048);         
BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(1024, 2048,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
for (int y = 0; y < 2048; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 1024; x++) {
        int value = image[x][y];
        theImage.setRGB(x, y, value);
    }
}
File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);
```

Comment: try to make your code more simplified. Do not paste everything here and expect us to find the problem for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I will edit and simplify it, thanks for the response.

Comment: Your code formation is awful. Please take more care next time.

Comment: It would probably also help to attach a (small) sample file.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing uint16 data in an int array, this may lead to loss/corruption of data.

Following post discusses similar issue:

[Java read unsigned int, store, and write it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512298/java-read-unsigned-int-store-and-write-it-back)

Comment: Why would it cause data loss or corruption? A Java `int` is signed 32 bit, that's more than enough room to store the 16 bits of the uint16...

Comment: @haraldK. You are right. I was mixing up Java and C datatype sizes.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly read and display an image originally stored as `uint16`, it's best to use the `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` type. A Java `short` is 16 bit, and the [`DataBufferUShort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBufferUShort.html) is made for storing unsigned 16 bit values.

Try this:

```
InputStream is = ...;
DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(is);

BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(1024, 2048, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);

short[] pixels = ((DataBufferUShort) theImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    pixels[i] = data.readShort(); // short value is signed, but DataBufferUShort will take care of the "unsigning"
}

// TODO: close() streams in a finally block
```

To convert the image further to an 8 bit image, you can create a new image and draw the original onto that:

```
BufferedImage otherImage = new BufferedImage(1024, 2048, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics2D g = otherImage.createGraphics();
try {
    g.drawImage(theImage, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
   g.dispose();
}
```

Now you can store `otherImage` as an eight bit grayscale PNG.